# FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified / tempfile

Tags: python, temporary-files

I need to get 16-bit photogrammetry targets and so am trying to use the code from this wedsite: https://mpetroff.net/2018/05/photogrammetry-targets/, but it gives the error when it tries to create temporary directory with tempfile and I don't seem to understand why.

```
with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tmp_dir:
# Create sheets of targets in temporary directory
pdfs = []
for n in range(math.ceil(len(CODES) / ROWS / COLUMNS)):
    pdf_filename = os.path.join(tmp_dir, str(n) + '.pdf')
    create_sheet(n, pdf_filename)
    pdfs.append(pdf_filename)
# Combine sheets into a single PDF
subprocess.run(['pdftk'] + pdfs + ['cat', 'output', FILENAME])
```

Comment: maybe `FILENAME` should be `pdf_filename`? You also need to create the file first before you start appending to it.

Comment: `tempfile` on Windows looks for C:\TEMP, C:\TMP, \TEMP, or \TMP, make sure one of those directories exists, if not just create an empty one.